# Deploying a new database on a new server, an msbuild ssdt rookie issue

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, sql-server-data-tools

I have this issue, but I don't know which user to should I give dbo permission when the one making deployments to the server is the sqlpackage with msbuild and not an actual user.

```
*** Could not deploy package.
 Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 262, Level 14, State 1, Line 1 CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.
 Error SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:
 CREATE DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
 ON
 PRIMARY(NAME = [$(DatabaseName)], FILENAME = N'$(DefaultDataPath)$(DefaultFilePrefix)_Primary.mdf')
 LOG ON (NAME = [$(DatabaseName)_log], FILENAME = N'$(DefaultLogPath)$(DefaultFilePrefix)_Primary.ldf') COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Things I've already tried:

- Give full permissions to NETWORKSERVICE
- Give full permissions to SYSTEM
- Checked the TCP/IP Connection properties (just in case, but unuseful since the problem says permissions...)
- **@EDIT**: Give sysadmin permissions to DOMAIN\MY_COMPILER_COMPUTER$

I hope this is an easy one for those experienced with this.

Comment: TFS build service usually is setup under domain account, this is the user context build executes under, check on your build machine either services or TFS managment app.

Comment: @drk it's local, I had been doing a lab, within my own pc with msbuild and tfs, even more, I gave sysadmin permissions no the db to the machine. Maybe in the events of the system should I find something? where should I be looking for?